# Java 'Could not find main class' for .jar even though its written in manifest.mf

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, ant, jar

I'm using Netbeans to build a jar. When I press f6, the project runs fine within Netbeans. However, if I go into my /dist/ folder and try to run the .jar, it just opens it as if it were a .zip. If I try to run the project from command line, I get the 'Could not find main class' error. However if I browse the .jar, and look in the META-INF/manifest.mf file, I can see that it did describe a main class within it.

My packages are named as myname.project, and the main class is named myname.project.Main.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Is myname.project.Main in the jar file under myname/project/Main.class ?

Comment: I assume you did *not* use any code scrambling?

Comment: Please post the manifest.mf content and your main class content.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, the file is there in the folder myname/project/Main.class

Comment: @Fildor No code scrambling, I built it as a normal project from within Netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to run a runnable jar-file is with the `-jar` switch.

```
java -jar path/to/file.jar
```

An alternative way to run a jar file without the mainclass specified in the manifest (or if there are several main classes for some reason would be the standard

```
java -cp path/to/file.jar com.foo.Main
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running it from `command-line` using the command `$ java -cp bar.jar X` where X is your main class without the `.class` extension. If it runs, it's a problem with the manifest structure.

Comment: That works! However if I just do `java /path/to/Project.jar` then i get the same 'could not find main class' error

Comment: This means there must be a typo or illegal character in the `manifest.mf` file.

Comment: That means your `manifest.mf` is not proper(illegal characters,unexpected closure) or it's not properly included in the project path.

Comment: Could it be this part of the manifest: `Created-By: 1.7.0_11-b21 (Oracle Corporation)`?

Comment: How about running it with `java -jar /path/to/Project.jar`? Or did you just forget the -jar switch from your earlier post?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Replace this lineof your manifest  `Class-Path: lib/swt-debug.jar lib/swt.jar` with this `Class-Path: lib/swt-debug.jar lib/swt.jar Project.classpath` where Project is your jar file name

Comment: If that doesn't help , try replacing entire value of classpath with a `dot(.)`

Comment: @Kayaman That was it.. adding `-jar` to the command makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. `-jar` should always be included while running a `jar`

Comment: @user2067771 Sorry, I'm a noob. Thanks for your help!